# Ignoring multiple NaNs when calculating standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe which contains some 5 minute intraday data.  DeltaBetweenClose is `NaN` for the first trade bar in the day when market opens(9:30 EST).

```
    time     Date       symbol    DeltaBetweenClose 
    9:35    2017-07-17  spy        NaN 
    9:40    2017-07-17  spy       -1.2                     
    ..........................................
    ..........................................    
    16:00   2018-07-17  spy        1.7
    9:35    2017-07-18  spy        NaN
    9:40    2017-07-18  spy        0.3                      
    ..........................................
    ..........................................        
    9:35    2018-07-17  nflx       NaN
```

I am trying to create a column `CloseDelta_sd` that calculates a rolling standard deviation of `DeltaBetweenClose` column grouped by `symbol`s that looks into the prior 30 bars and calculates standard deviation while ignoring `NaN`s. My following attempt returns all `NaN`s. It works when there is only one `NaN` at the top of the  `DeltaBetweenClose` column.

```
df['CloseDelta_sd'] = df.groupby('symbol').DeltaBetweenClose.transform(lambda x: x.rolling(30).std())
```

Comment: `std` has an option to skipna, which is true by default

Comment: @user3483203 `skipna` defaults to true. Should I put it explicitly?

Comment: You shouldn't have to.  You probably need to set `min_periods` to `1` in `rolling`

Comment: @user3483203 wow that did it! what was your initial hypothesis behind what might be happening?

Comment: @user3483203 Would you mind posting your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't with `std`, since that skips `NaN` by default, but instead with `rolling`.

You need to make use of the [`min_periods`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) parameter:

> Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value (otherwise result is NA). For a window that is specified by an offset, this will default to 1.

Since you provide an `int` instead of an offset, you will end up with a lot of `NaN` groups, the fix is simple:

```
(df.groupby('symbol').DeltaBetweenClose
    .transform(lambda x: x.rolling(30, min_periods=1).std()))
```